# How do i display one integer from activity to widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have to activity in my app. One activity is being used for increasing the count value and other activity extends the AppWidget. As I need to display count value(Integer) into app widget regularly.

Here is my activity code.

Smoke_Count.java

```
package com.example.smokecount;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Smoke_Count extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{


    private Button btn;
    private TextView txt;
    private static int count=0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_smoke__count);

        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txt.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        btn.setOnTouchListener(this);
        loadInt();


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.smoke__count, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            loadInt();
            saveInt("countValue", count);
            count++;
            txt.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void saveInt(String key,int count)
    {
        SharedPreferences share= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        Editor edit= share.edit();
        edit.putInt(key, count);
        edit.commit();

    }

    public void loadInt()
    {
        SharedPreferences share= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        int counter=share.getInt("countValue", count);
        /*Intent i=new Intent(Smoke_Count.this, Widget.class);
        i.putExtra("count", counter);
        sendBroadcast(i);*/
        txt.setText(String.valueOf(counter));

        if(counter>=count)
        {
            count=counter;
        }


    }

}
```

And this is my widget activity

Widget.java

```
package com.example.smokecount;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider{



        @Override
        public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                int[] appWidgetIds) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);



            for(int i=0;i<appWidgetIds.length;i++)
            {
                int appWidgetID=appWidgetIds[i];

                Intent i1=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, null, context, Smoke_Count.class);
                PendingIntent pending=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i1, 0);

                RemoteViews views=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_widget);
                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton1, pending);
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetID, views);
            }
        }

        /*@Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
            String action=intent.getAction();
        Bundle ext=intent.getExtras();
        int scount=ext.getInt("count");
        Toast.makeText(context, ""+scount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }*/

}
```

This is my widget xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtcount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I need to display a count value into the widget.

This is logcat

```
06-30 18:00:36.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2226): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 18:00:36.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2226): Process: com.example.smokecount, PID: 2226
06-30 18:00:36.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2226): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.smokecount.Widget: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-30 18:00:36.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2407)
06-30 18:00:36.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-30 18:00:36.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
06-30 18:00:36.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-30 18:00:36.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-30 18:00:36.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
06-30 18:00:36.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 18:00:36.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-30 18:00:36.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
06-30 18:00:36.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
06-30 18:00:36.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-30 18:00:36.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2226): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-30 18:00:36.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at com.example.smokecount.Widget.onReceive(Widget.java:42)
06-30 18:00:36.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2400)
06-30 18:00:36.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: answer me sir @pareshmayani

Answer (score 0):

That area which is commented is the part for transfering the int. So you need to putExtra("key", intValue) in the Activty and receive the int in Widget on getIntent().getExtras().getInt("key")

Otherwise you can grab the Int by using the SharedPreferences as you did before.

So lets say in Activity:

```
Intent i=new Intent(Smoke_Count.this, Widget.class);
i.putExtra("count", counter);
```

and in the Widget

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
int yourInt = bundle.getInt("count", 0);
```

**edit**

As you already have worked with, you should rather use the given intent instead of the getIntent(), this causes the NullpointerException, so do like:

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
int yourInt = bundle.getInt("count", 0);
```

Comment: Getting error while using onRecieve method in widget activity @mapo

Comment: can you post the LogCat?

Comment: can you tell what you've got on line 42 in Widget.java?

Comment: this is the code which is at line 42 int yourInt = bundle.getInt("count", 0);   @mapo